# Add column to existing table from input field in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use pdo and mysql and I already know how to add a column to an existing table, but when I try it with value from an input field, the name of the variable $.... is being added as column.
The code I have to add the value from the input field as column, is as followed:

```
public function insertAlterTable($colName)
{
    $this->pdo = $this->connectMySql();
    $query = 'ALTER TABLE nbs_events ADD $colName CHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT "nee"';
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        return false;
    }
    $this->pdo = null;
    return true;
}
```

This code is wrapped inside a try catch block.
And also inside a class.
At the frontpage I use this code like:

```
insertAlterTable($_POST['colname']);
```

How can I add the value from the input field `colname` as column to the existing table.
Please help.

**I've updated the code as followed, so it works for me:**

```
public function insertAlterTable($colName)
{ 
    $colName = mysql_real_escape_string($colName);
    $this->pdo = $this->connectMySql();
    $query = "ALTER TABLE nbs_events ADD $colName CHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT \"nee\"";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        return false;
    }
    $this->pdo = null;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You really shouldn't use the `$_POST['colname']` variable here, this is a big security hole as anyone can inject sql as he likes.

Comment: @acme I thought the prepare statement would take care of that so I don't need to use for example `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: You're basically right, but you are gluing your string together on your own instead of using the input parameters along with `execute`. Therefore there is no auto escaping.

Comment: @acme see my update in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, when using single quotes, variables are not expanded.

```
 $a = "hello";
 $b = "$a dude";               // $b is now "hello dude"
 $c = '$a dude';               // $c is now "$a dude"
```

Use double quotes or string concatenation and you are fine:

```
 $query = "ALTER TABLE nbs_events ADD $colName CHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT \"nee\"";
```

More in The Fine Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: If have tried to add double quotes around the $colName in the query but then nothing is added and the function will return false;

Comment: Yeah I have, and tried several things, but can't get it to work.

Comment: I updated my answer. Did you try that? In if it doesn't work, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yeah that worked, so it had something to do with the single/double quotes.